# How can I solve SPI problem for Write-Read?

Tags: c, stm32, spi

I am writting to register some value with SPI and reading them. But I write 237, first time I read 230 second time 235 but every time changing. What can cause that problem ? I added my code block at the below. How can I solve or how can i determine the problem ?

I added SPI configuratioın and SPI senddata8 and receive data function at the below.  ( I configurated the CS pin another function)

```
void enc28_writeOp(unsigned char op, unsigned char address, unsigned char data)
{
    unsigned char dat = 0;

    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);

    dat = (op | (address & ADDR_MASK));

    BSP_SPI1SendByte(dat);
    Delay(100);

    dat = data;

    BSP_SPI1SendByte(dat);
    Delay(100);

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);
}

unsigned char enc28_readOp(unsigned char oper, unsigned char addr)
{
    unsigned char dat = 0;
    GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);
    Delay(2);

    dat = (oper | (addr & ADDR_MASK));
    BSP_SPI1SendByte(dat);
    dat = BSP_SPI1SendByte(0xFF);

    if (addr & 0x80)
    {
        dat = BSP_SPI1SendByte(0xFF);
    }

    GPIO_SetBits(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_4);

    return dat;
}

unsigned char BSP_SPI1SendByte(unsigned char byte)
{
    uint16_t timeout;
    //It is done in order to prevent the program hesitatng.
    timeout = TIMEOUT_TIME;
    while ((SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE) == RESET) & (timeout != 0))
    {
        timeout--;
    }

    SPI_SendData8(SPI1, byte);
    Delay(100);
    timeout = TIMEOUT_TIME;
    while ((SPI_I2S_GetFlagStatus(SPI1, SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE) == RESET) & (timeout != 0))
    {
        timeout--;
    }

}
```

SPI Configuration:

```
#define TIMEOUT_TIME 0x2000
void BSP_ConfigSPI1(void)
{
    SPI_InitTypeDef SPI_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

    // /* Enable SPI1 and GPIOA clocks */
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_SPI1, ENABLE);
    RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_5 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
    // GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);



    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource5, GPIO_AF_5); //spi
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource6, GPIO_AF_5); //spi
    GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource7, GPIO_AF_5); //spi

    /* SPI1 configuration */
    SPI_I2S_DeInit(SPI1);
    SPI_StructInit(&SPI_InitStructure);
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Direction = SPI_Direction_2Lines_FullDuplex;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_Mode = SPI_Mode_Master;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_DataSize = SPI_DataSize_8b;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPOL = SPI_CPOL_Low;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CPHA = SPI_CPHA_2Edge;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BaudRatePrescaler_32; // 72Mhz / 4 = 18Mhz --> ENC28J60 SPI OK
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_FirstBit = SPI_FirstBit_MSB;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_CRCPolynomial = 7;
    SPI_InitStructure.SPI_NSS = SPI_NSS_Soft;
    SPI_Init(SPI1, &SPI_InitStructure);
    SPI_RxFIFOThresholdConfig(SPI1, SPI_RxFIFOThreshold_QF);

    SPI_DataSizeConfig(SPI1, ENABLE);
    /* Enable SPI1  */
    SPI_Cmd(SPI1, ENABLE);
}
void SPI_SendData8(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx, uint8_t Data)
{
  uint32_t spixbase = 0x00;

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_SPI_ALL_PERIPH(SPIx));

  spixbase = (uint32_t)SPIx;
  spixbase += 0x0C;

  *(__IO uint8_t *)spixbase = Data;
}

uint8_t SPI_ReceiveData8(SPI_TypeDef *SPIx)
{
  uint32_t spixbase = 0x00;

  /* Check the parameters */
  assert_param(IS_SPI_ALL_PERIPH_EXT(SPIx));

  spixbase = (uint32_t)SPIx;
  spixbase += 0x0C;

  return *(__IO uint8_t *)spixbase;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your initialization routine(s).

Comment: Okey I added at the below

Comment: Are you writing registers in an external device and you try to read them back or do you mean writing to SPI internal registers and reading them back. What is your external device? Have you checked your SPI signal levels with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope?

Comment: @A.R.C. I am using Enc28j60 ethernet shild and I want to communicate between STM32 and Enc38 using SPI communication. I want to write MAC address to device register and read it.

Comment: Change the prescaler to 256 and see if the problem persists.

Comment: @KamilCuk yes it persists. I changed

Comment: Problems with wrong SPI results are almost always caused by [clock skew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_skew). You need to check the _clock phase_ (where does it sample data) and _clock polarity_ (active high/low) expected by the slave device and then setup SPI accordingly.

Comment: I check my SPI pins, added while loop and set I can not see any signal on my osciloscope.

Comment: I cant find any solution please help me. I saw spi signal but wrong signal. And than I added 22 Ohm between the stm and enc's SPI pins. And now I am getting evry time different value